# EntityFramework 4.3 issue when calling SaveChanges multiple times with Concurrency Check

Tags: entity-framework-4.3

*-- Changed the scope of the question because this other piece of code is easier to explain but it's just the same behavior as the one that made me write the first version of the question...*

There is something strange with EF 4.3.1 Concurrency Check and the automatic caching when calling `SaveChanges()` more than once.

When using EF 4.3 (with the hardcoded column type bug and all) the same piece of code works fine (probably because there were no concurrency check). When using 4.3.1 the second `SaveChanges()` call crashes as bellow.

Here are the classes:

```
public class Concurrent
{
   public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}

public class Operation : Concurrent
{
   public virtual int CustomIdName { get; set; }
   public virtual C1 C1 { get; set; }
   public virtual C2 C2 { get; set; }
   // other properties
}

public class C1 : Concurrent
{
   public virtual string CustomIdName { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<C2> C2 { get; set; }
   // other properties
}

public class C2 : Concurrent
{
   public virtual string CustomIdName { get; set; }
   // other properties...
}

public class Repository : DbContext, IMyCustomGenericRepository
{
   public void Save() { SaveChanges(); }
   public T Find<T>(object id) { return Set<T>().Find(id); }
   // other methods from the interface and all...

   public Repository Recreate() { return new Repository(); }
}
```

Some coding...

```
public void TestMethod(IMyCustomGenericRepository Repository)
{
   var operation = Repository.Find<Operation>(1); // ok
   operation.C1 = Repository.Find<C1>("1"); // ok
   operation.C2 = Repository.Find<C2>("1"); // ok
   Repository.Save(); // ok

   operation = Repository.Find<Operation>(1); // ok
   operation.C1 = Repository.Find<C1>("1"); // ok
   operation.C2 = Repository.Find<C2>("2"); // ok
   Repository.Save(); // fails
}

public void OtherTestMethod(IMyCustomGenericRepository Repository)
{
   var operation = Repository.Find<Operation>(1); // ok
   operation.C1 = Repository.Find<C1>("1"); // ok
   operation.C2 = Repository.Find<C2>("1"); // ok
   Repository.Save(); // ok

   Repository = Repository.Recreate();

   operation = Repository.Find<Operation>(1); // ok
   operation.C1 = Repository.Find<C1>("1"); // ok
   operation.C2 = Repository.Find<C2>("2"); // ok
   Repository.Save(); // ok
}
```

My Fluent API looks like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>().HasKey(_o => _o.CustomIdName);
modelBuilder.Entity<Operation>().Property(_o => _o.Version).HasColumnType("timestamp").IsConcurrencyToken();

modelBuilder.Entity<C1>().HasKey(_c1 => _c1.CustomIdName);
modelBuilder.Entity<C1>().Property(_c1 => _c1.Version).HasColumnType("timestamp").IsConcurrencyToken();

modelBuilder.Entity<C2>().HasKey(_c2 => _c2.CustomIdName);
modelBuilder.Entity<C2>().Property(_c2 => _c2.Version).HasColumnType("timestamp").IsConcurrencyToken();
```

The only diference from the first method to the second is the call to `Repository.Recreate()` method which returns a whole new repository.

### Update 2

Inside the Context class I've overritten the SaveChanges() method to this:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
   // saves pending changes
   var _returnValue = base.SaveChanges();


   // updates EF local entities (cache)
   foreach (var item in Set<Operation>().Local)
      (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, item);
   foreach (var item in Set<C1>().Local)
      (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, item);
   foreach (var item in Set<C2>().Local)
      (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, item);


   // returns the saving result
   return _returnValue;
}
```

This piece of code *"solved"* the issue so it **IS** as I thought: SQL server automatically changes the TimeStamp value (concurrency token) but EF doesn't update that value on the property Version for some reason I still don't know.

The problem is that with the wrong version I cannot save again simply because I'd violate the concurrency check from EF.

Refreshing local entities (automatically cached entities by EF) prevents this issue **BUT** with a major side-effect: I'll have to manually refresh every changed entry. This isn't funny at all because:

1. Detecting local entities (casts and other things)
2. Iterating into every local entity and refreshing it's status
3. If this is to be forgotten than the issue will happen again.

Why EF does not automatically update the version colunm (set as `IsConcurrencyToken()`) just as it does with the PK column (that gets updated after insert if the PK is an identity column)?

### Update 3 (possible solution?)

Overriding the SaveChanges() method from the DBContext and placing this code seems to get it all working quite fine:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
   var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(_entry => _entry.State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached && _entry.State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged && _entry.State != System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted).Select(_entry => _entry.Entity).ToArray();

   if (!Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled)
      ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

   var result = base.SaveChanges();

   foreach (var entity in entities)
      (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.Refresh(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity);

   return result;
}
```

It's not a perfect solution.
But it's automatic enought for now.
Should do the trick for a while until a better answer shows up.

Comment: Can you show the entities and the code for this problem? I'd like to test it.

Comment: @Slauma Just added some code. Looks like the caching from EF is messing with the concurrency check. It's the only thing I can think of from the tests I have made so far...

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue on simple data reads where one page sets a property to an entity and the next page shows a grid which doesn't reflect the change consistently until 7 minutes or so. The grid allows you to click reload and it makes an AJAX post to get fresh data but that property toggles between new/old value randomly for the first 7 to 10 minutes.

Comment: I had the same problem @diegohb, but this question is about a slightly different problem. The issue you describe is fixed by using .AsNoTracking() on your grid page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202733/entity-framework-and-caching-changes-are-tracking-back-to-cache http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/04/entity-framework-and-asnotracking.html

Comment: I was preparing to give that a try. Also to test the new EF 5 with it's new items but them both are yet on the planned state as we have some other priorities to deal with. But thanks, really, for the tip.

Comment: Did you try using ObjextContext.MergeOptions?

Answer (score 0):

I have also similar problem with EF 4.3.1.
Just did the upgrade and it broke my working code based on 4.1.

I cannot add new entities which have relations it seems. e.g. A new place object with a relation to a Country object.
All my entities have a Concurrency property:

> this.Property(t =>
>   t.lastChangedDate).HasColumnName("lastChangedDate").IsConcurrencyToken().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

I update this property self before CRUD e.g.

```
virtual public void Save(T target)
{
    target.ID = GuidUtils.GenerateComb();
    target.creationDate = DateTime.Now;
    target.lastChangedDate = DateTime.Now;

    sessionManager.Set<T>().Add(target);
    sessionManager.SaveChanges();
}
```

When i save a new place object i get:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

hmmm...did i mention this was working code?

If i remove the concurrency part in the Country Map it works...
For the record, the country used to relate the place object to is stored in the database correctly prior to when storing the place object. I can see its PK and the concurrency property.

So it seems like a reference concurrency problem in 4.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

ok, a small update here.

1. It was not right saying it worked in previous version. We were using 4.1 with PostgreSQL database and Devart connector... there this worked. Strange, i don't understand.
2. The workaround of LordALMMa Also works for me. But i don't want to use a workaround....

@LordALMMa have you found a solution yet?

update 7-4-12

I changed my concurrency code. First i was using a DateTime property as this:

```
this.Property(t => t.lastChangedDate).IsConcurrencyToken().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

At avery update or insert i manually update this property to DateTime.Now. 
This was together with PostgreSQL and devart connector and worked fine. After migrating to MS SQL i got into the problems. I now changed this to:

```
this.Property(t => t.timestamp).HasColumnName("timestamp").IsRowVersion();
```

This works! strange....because i was not doing something illegal..
This column in the MS database is of type rowversion.

So somehow a non database generated timestamp of type DateTime is not working in MS SQL using keywords `IsConcurrencyToken` and  `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)`

.