# Entity Framework and caching - Changes are tracking back to cache

Tags: model-view-controller, caching, entity-framework-4

I have some data being pulled in from an Entity model. This contains attributes of items, let's  say car parts with max-speed, weight and size. Since there are a lot of parts and the base attributes never change, I've cached all the records.

Depending on the car these parts are used in, these attributes might now be changed, so I setup a new car, copy the values from the cached item "Engine" to the new car object and then add "TurboCharger", which boosts max speed, weight and size of the Engine.

The problem I'm running into is that it seems that the Entity model is still tracking the context *back* to the cached data. So when weight is increased by the local method, it increases it for all users. I tried adding **"MergeOption.NoTracking"** to my context as this is supposed to remove all entity tracking, but it still seems to be tracking back. If I turn off the cache, it works fine as it pulls fresh values from the database each time.

If I want to copy a record from my entity model, is there a way I can say "Copy the object but treat it as a standard object with no history of coming from entity" so that once my car has the attributes from an item, it is just a flattened object?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not too sure about MergeOption.NoTracking on the whole context and exactly what that does but what you can do as an alternative is to add .AsNoTracking() into your query from the database. This will definitely return a detached object.
Take a look here for some details on AsNoTracking usage : http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/04/entity-framework-and-asnotracking.html.

The other thing is to make sure you enumerate your collection before you insert to the cache to ensure that you arent acting within the queriable, ie use .ToArray().

The other option is to manually detach the object from the context (using Detach(T entity)).

Comment: I had tried using .NoTracking before, but I believe this is only if you are using DbContext. But, you mentioned Detach(T entity). I pulled my records, ran detach on the context (I always though you ran it on the objects returned, not the context!) and BAM, every things working perfectly in the cache! Thank you sir! :D